# Designing common server side for mobile and web application

Tags: web-applications, architecture, server-side, software-design, mobile-application

I have a project where I should develop a mobile application(android) and a website. As both of them have the same database/content and functionality **I want to write common sever side for mobile and web application.**

Now I have two options:

1. *To develop a RESTful Web service* on the server side to which
   my android app and website(HTML/Javascript) will communicate. I think it's not a comfortable way for website development, because you have fill all HTML components value using javascript on page load.
2. *Develop a web application with MVC* framework (for example CodeIgniter) where each page will have two views:
     a) common HTML/CSS/Javascript page for Web site

   b) JSON data for mobile application. In this case mobile app will make a HTTP GET call to URL: www.mySite/someParameters and it'll respond JSON data as a result.

Which one is better to choose?

Or, Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: shouldn't be RESTful (I've edited it with the correct acronym) exactly what you have explained in point 2? see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), "Applied to web services". However yes, I would follow this idea (two points, one idea!) for sure.

Comment: @Sigismondo Yes, of course, it'll be RESTfull. Please see the point 1, I've added some additional description. The main advantage in point 2 is that you're developing website as usual, what you additionally do for mobile app is that you just add a view where JSON data is shown instead of HTML.
Personally I prefer the second point, but I'm interested how people develop such kind of applications. What is best practice?

Comment: Once it's RESTful the view can be realized as you prefer, following other constraints. For example, you can have a look to... stackoverflow itself! Here is the API documentation: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs - here you can find many apps or skins: http://stackapps.com/ - have a look to the mobile site of SO too. If your app is on par with this level of "dynamics" this is a good option... but if you start needing more feedbacks, using OpenGL graphics, not needing iOS portability, a native app is more flexible.

Comment: oh yes, not being a web developer (yet?), I do prefer option 2 as well :)

Answer (score 6):

I prefer build a web application in this way:

1. Web application with java [Spring](http://spring.io/)
2. Create  a REST interface, usually with two output, JSON and XML, for example `http://localhost:8080/hello` and `http://localhost:8080/greeting.xml`
3. Use some client side framework I prefer [boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to have a
   responsive layout.
4. Use an MVC client side, like [knockoutjs.com](http://knockoutjs.com).
5. AJAX calls, where I call the url /hello I map the result to
   knockoutjs binding, in this way I have a bidirectional binding.
6. Build a native application for Android or iPhone using the
   interfaces.

   I hope it can be useful

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on (a) how comfortable you are with either solution and (b) the requirements of the project. I would prefer (1) because I don't know any web frameworks, but I am very familiar with network programming. It would be simple to write some back end application serve the HTML page. However, if it was a large project, then it would be advantageous to choose (2).

If just want to get something done and you don't see any advantage / disadvantage to either solution, then just choose one.